# How to model relationships in scenario where every product can (don't have to) be associated to only one category

Tags: domain-driven-design, relationships, aggregate

This one still occupies my mind. How do you model 1:N relationships.

Consider having a category and product (typical e-commerce scenario).
Every product can (don't have to) be associated to only one category.

Should I model such relationship as: (pseudo-code)

```
Product
{
    Category category;
}

Category {}
```

or on Category's side:

```
Category
{
    Product[] products;
}

Product {}
```

Second way seems more logical (products are organized in categories) but brings other problems (imagine category with 10k products and every time you want to add product to collection, you must check whether it contains that product or not.

The first way makes it easier. There is always one Category and Product in memory, but Category entity without behavior seems awkward.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is/will be the most common access pattern? Will you be mostly presenting a category with a product, or a list of products with a category?

Comment: I've never worked on e-commerce sites, but I usually find this kind of relationship data is simply stored in the database, and does not need to be carried around by each "code object" at all. If the data needs to be there, what form it should take depends entirely on how you're using it. Are categories only ever used as a bucket of products? Is a product completely useless without its categories? Is there more to a category than its name? Could the relationship be a totally separate third class? Does it even make sense for Category to be a class, instead of a field on Product?

Comment: Imagine how you will use "second way structure" if you need to display one product information with `Category` name.

Comment: @Fabio By performing additional query or... The relationship doesn't have to be same in Domain and Read model (when using some form of CQRS).

Comment: @Ixrec Yes. What if there is rule that every customer can buy products only from categories he's allowed to?

Comment: Making category a field on Product would work pretty well for enforcing that rule.

Comment: @Ixrec True. Same will go for user I guess. I just had that feeling that it (in real world) would make more sense for category to contain products, but I'm starting to see pitfalls in this decision.

Comment: Yes, trying to make an object hierarchy correspond to a real-world ontology generally doesn't work that well. It's usually better to start with the operations you want to perform on your data (in this case, there's not much a user can do with a "category" other than look at the products in it).

Comment: It sounds like you're making the mistake of looking at your domain through  the structural requirements of an RDBMS and a 3rd normal form schema. In other words, you're couching the problem in terms of related tabular data that can be held by an RDBMS. Ignore the persistence, and focus on the behaviour of the domain in terms of the domain language. WHY are you categorising products? For what purpose? In what CONTEXT does a product have to have a categorisation?

Comment: @Matt It's categorised mostly for filtering and as I mentioned, there is rule  that every customer can buy products only from categories he's allowed to. Also there is a rule, that product can be only in one category (imho product AR should protect this invariant).